# Repeated measures anova in R

Tags: anova, mixed-model, variance, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I have a dataset containing percentage scores for 15 participants. There are two observations for every participant, one with an intervention and one with a placebo in a double-blind design. Each participant receives the intervention exactly once, either at the first or second day. The dataset looks like this:

```
condition     subject  day  score
placebo        1        1    90%
verum          1        2    92%
etc...
```

I now want to evaluate interactions between "condition" and "day" as well as "score".
I've tried setting up a repeated-measures anova in r like this:

```
my.aov <- with(subjects, aov(score ~ condition + Error(subject / score)))
```

In the summary it tells me

```
          Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
condition       1 0.000116 0.000116   0.059  0.811
Residuals 14 0.027298 0.001950
```

Is this an appropriate method for my data? Can I safely understand this to mean that inter-subject differences (my Error) are greater than effects? What further methods should I use to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I would set up the analysis this way (using R)

```
library(lme4)
mod <- lmer(score ~ condition*day + (1 | subject), data=your_data_frame)
summary(mod)
```

You say *want to evaluate interactions between "condition" and "day"*, but the model you have written does not admit interactions. Within the main effects model you have estimated (no effect for `day`), the null hypothesis of no effect of `condition` cannot be rejected at a nominal 5% level.